# Does anyone know what is wrong with my VLOOKUP formula? It works fine from F6-F16, except that when it comes to "Standard" category

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

Here is my **`VLOOKUP`**

```
formula:=VLOOKUP(E6,$H$6:$I$9,IF(E6="Overtime",2,IF(E6="Standard",2,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like all of the possibilities in E6 result in 2; i.e. column I.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the optional last parameter `Range_lookup`.  if it is omitted, it defaults to `TRUE` which means

> find the closest match in the first column (sorted in ascending order).

If the first column isn't sorted in ascending order, results can be unpredictable (as you have found).

Specifying `Range_lookup = FALSE` will only find exact matches and the lookup column can be unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to multiply the hours worked by the payrate?
If so, I would have used Vlookup like this and ended up charging the client about twice as much :)

```
=VLOOKUP(E6,$H$6:$I$9,2,FALSE)*D6
```